# Is is possible to do a batch update with JDO on Google Appengine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo, datanucleus

I have an application on Appengine that updates multiple entities wihtin the same datastore transaction. The updates are done by calling the setters of the entities.

I've set up the appstats tool to watch the API calls generated by my code.

My updates are only processed when the persistence manager is closed (after the transaction is commited), and they are processed one by one (one API call for each update).

Is there a way in JDO/Appengine to force the updates to happen in the transaction and with a single bath api call ?

This is a real problem since Google announced the new pricing model, because datastore writes are quite expensive now.

Answer (score 0):

Can it be that you have this in your configuration?

```
<property name="datanucleus.appengine.autoCreateDatastoreTxns" value="false"/>
```

If so try setting it to true, see http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/overview.html#Disabling_Transactions_and_Porting_Existing_JDO_Apps for more information.